# Remove shadow and transparency during transition

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, uiviewanimationtransition

I'm trying to develop an application using a side menu and some navigation controller.
Everything is working fine, but I've pointed out an issue on pushing detail view controllers.

[image]

I tried to remove shadow using:

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
```

I set up background color of each nav controller and subview to white, and setting translucency to false for each navigation bar.
I cannot figure out what kind of problem it could be.